# mysqldump in cron not working

Tags: centos, cron, mysql

I am trying to do a `mysqldump` on the `cron` for every 5 minutes but it seems that it is not working. I try to execute the `mysqldump` and it works fine.

**`mysqldump`**

```
mysqldump -uroot -ppassword --single_transaction --opt dbname | gzip > /home/myhome/backup/dbname.`date +"%T"`.sql.gz
```

**`cron`**

```
*/5 * * * * mysqldump -uroot -ppassword --single_transaction --opt dbname | gzip > /home/myhome/backup/dbname.`date +"%T"`.sql.gz
```

**LOG**

```
May 17 04:35:42 CentOS-63-64-minimal crontab[5605]: (root) LIST (root)
May 17 04:40:01 CentOS-63-64-minimal CROND[5626]: (root) CMD (mysqldump -uroot -ppassword --single_transaction --opt dbname | gzip > /home/myhome/backup/dbname.`date +")
```

**UPDATE**

I think I found the problem, it is in `date +"%T"`, because if I replace it with `date -I` it now works. However, I need to append a date & time on the filename.

Comment: What's in your log files?

Comment: @DavidW - see my edit please, thanks. I list the last two lines on my log.

Comment: I had this problem & the 'duplicate' question was not helpful. The solution I found: you need to escape the ampersand. Try this for your filename: dbname.`date +\%T`.sql.gz (I cannot post this as an answer as this question is marked as a duplicate)

Answer (score 0):

This should be a path problem for the cron entry.

Try to use `/usr/bin/mysqldump` instead of `mysqldump`, `/usr/bin/gzip` instead of `gzip` only, and `/usr/bin/date` instead of `date`.  Change the path accordingly to your system. Use command `whereis` to find the paths for the commands.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your command in a script, i.e backupmysql, then add this entry in cron:

> */5 * * * * /path/to/backupmysql